# Migrations SQL script file generated using dotnet ef command is not valid for Azure MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, .net, azure, entity-framework-core, azure-pipelines

**We want to setup CI/CD for automatic database schema migration for Azure MySQL database**

However we are facing issue with the migration script generated.

If you can see below is our generated migration script.

```
START TRANSACTION;
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `__EFMigrationsHistory` WHERE `MigrationId` = '20210625071551_v1')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE `activitytype` (
        `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        `ShortName` varchar(20) NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
    );
END ;
COMMIT;
```

We have setup build pipeline for automatic generations of the migration scripts. And in release pipeline, We are using above attached migration script file to deploy changes on Azure MySQL DB but its giving us an error.

- MySQL version on Azure: 8.0
- DotNet version: .net 5

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `__EFMigrationsHistory` WHERE `MigrationId` = '20210' at line 1
> 2021-06-28T10:04:09.2150434Z ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\mysql-5.7.21-winx64\bin\mysql.exe' failed with exit code 1

The command which we are using in build pipeline:

```
dotnet ef migrations script -o $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\Migrations\migrationscript_cli.sql -i
```

Is there any way to generate script that will run successfully on MySQL?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text. Copy the original text to your question.

Comment: @JamesZ please check now, I have posted the exact problem and the link which you mentioned for the related answer not helping us for the same.